# Tensor flow lite model does not work after saving to file and loading to interpreter

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I am having a problem with running tensor flow lite model after saving it to file. Before it is exported to file it work fine, but after estimations are wrong. It happens both in Colab and it Android.

Below is my code from Colab:

Importing libraries

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers

print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)
```

My custom model

```
class Model(tf.Module):

  def __init__(self):
    self.loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")
    self.mae_metric = keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(name="mae")
    self.weights = []

    self.model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=[1], name='normalize'),
        layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', name='dense_1'),
        layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', name='dense_2'),
        layers.Dense(1, name='dense_3')
    ])

    self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1)
    self.loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

    self.model.compile(loss=self.loss,
                optimizer=self.optimizer)

    for layer in self.model.layers:
      if type(layer)==type(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()):
        # renorm=True, Can have renomalization for smaller batch sizes
        layer.momentum=0.9

  # The `train` function takes a batch of input data and labels.
  @tf.function(input_signature=[
      tf.TensorSpec([None], tf.float32),
      tf.TensorSpec([None], tf.float32)
  ])
  def train(self, x, y):
    loss2 = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      prediction = self.model(x, training=True)
      loss = loss2(y, prediction)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))
    self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
    self.mae_metric.update_state(y,  self.model(x, training=True))
    result = {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result(), "acc": self.mae_metric.result()}
    return result

  @tf.function(input_signature=[
      tf.TensorSpec([None], tf.float32),
  ])
  def infer(self, x):
    logits = self.model(x)
    return {
        "output": logits
    }

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)])
  def save(self, checkpoint_path):
    tensor_names = [weight.name for weight in self.model.weights]
    tensors_to_save = [weight.read_value() for weight in self.model.weights]
    tf.raw_ops.Save(
        filename=checkpoint_path, tensor_names=tensor_names,
        data=tensors_to_save, name='save')
    return {
        "checkpoint_path": checkpoint_path
    }

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)])
  def restore(self, checkpoint_path):
    restored_tensors = {}
    for var in self.model.weights:
      restored = tf.raw_ops.Restore(
          file_pattern=checkpoint_path, tensor_name=var.name, dt=var.dtype,
          name='restore')
      var.assign(restored)
      restored_tensors[var.name] = restored
    return restored_tensors
```

Saving model

```
m = Model()
# Save the trained weights to a checkpoint.
m.save('/tmp/model.ckpt')

SAVED_MODEL_DIR = "saved_model"

tf.saved_model.save(
    m,
    SAVED_MODEL_DIR,
    signatures={
        'train':
            m.train.get_concrete_function(),
        'infer':
            m.infer.get_concrete_function(),
        'save':
            m.save.get_concrete_function(),
        'restore':
            m.restore.get_concrete_function(),
    },
    options=tf.saved_model.SaveOptions(experimental_custom_gradients=True))

# Convert the model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(SAVED_MODEL_DIR)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,  # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS  # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
converter.experimental_enable_resource_variables = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

Training model and testing predictions

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
train = interpreter.get_signature_runner("train")
infer = interpreter.get_signature_runner("infer")

NUM_EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 500
epochs = np.arange(1, NUM_EPOCHS + 1, 1)
losses = np.zeros([NUM_EPOCHS])

train_data = np.zeros([BATCH_SIZE], dtype=np.float32)
train_label = np.zeros([BATCH_SIZE], dtype=np.float32)

for x in range(BATCH_SIZE):
  train_data[x] = (4000 - x)
  train_label[x] = x * 24

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_label))
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=BATCH_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
for i in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
  for x,y in train_ds:
    result3 = train(x = x, y = y)

  losses = result3['loss']
  acc = result3['acc']
  if (i + 1) % 10 == 0:
    print(f"Finished {i+1} epochs")
    print(f"loss: {losses}, acc: {acc}")

print("Finished training the model")
test_data = np.array([3000, 3500, 4000],  dtype=np.float32)
result = infer(x=test_data)
y = result["output"]
print(y)


result = infer(x=train_data)
y = result["output"]


def plot(x, y):
  plt.scatter(train_data, train_label, label='Data')
  plt.plot(x, y, color='k', label='Predictions')
  plt.xlabel('Capacity')
  plt.ylabel('Hours')
  plt.legend()

plot(train_data, y)
```

Above parts works fine
But if I save tensor flow lite model to file and load it, it doesn't. Predictions are completely wrong.

```
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

```
interpreter1 = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="model.tflite")
interpreter1.allocate_tensors()

NUM_EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 500
epochs1 = np.arange(1, NUM_EPOCHS + 1, 1)
losses1 = np.zeros([NUM_EPOCHS])

train_data1 = np.zeros([BATCH_SIZE], dtype=np.float32)
train_label1 = np.zeros([BATCH_SIZE], dtype=np.float32)

for x in range(BATCH_SIZE):
  train_data1[x] = (4000 - x)
  train_label1[x] = x * 24

train_ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data1, train_label1))
train_ds1 = train_ds1.shuffle(buffer_size=BATCH_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
for i in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
  for x,y in train_ds1:
    result3 = train(x = x, y = y)

  losses = result3['loss']
  acc = result3['acc']
  if (i + 1) % 10 == 0:
    print(f"Finished {i+1} epochs")
    print(f"loss: {losses}, acc: {acc}")
    

infer = interpreter1.get_signature_runner("infer")

test_data = np.array([3000, 3500, 4000],  dtype=np.float32)
result = infer(x=test_data)
y = result["output"]
print(y)

def plot_2(x, y):
  plt.scatter(train_data, train_label, label='Data')
  plt.plot(x, y, color='k', label='Predictions')
  plt.xlabel('Capacity')
  plt.ylabel('Hours')
  plt.legend()

plot_2(test_data, y)
```

Here is a link to my Colab code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Rc2OvzsIfT4BH9qUoX7BkgfeguTodhFL?usp=drive_link

To solve it I tried different approaches, but none worked.

While saving the model I am getting such warnings:

```
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as _update_step_xla while saving (showing 1 of 1). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
WARNING:absl:Importing a function (__inference_internal_grad_fn_3130) with ops with unsaved custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:absl:Importing a function (__inference_internal_grad_fn_3078) with ops with unsaved custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
```

But I am not sure if they have any impact.